# How could I rotate a 3D parametric equation onto another plane

Tags: matrices, rotations

If I have the parametric equation:

${x=t}$

${y=0}$

${z = 0 + -0.25x + 0.2x^2 + 0.1x^3}$

and I want to rotate it onto the plane:

$-{3x+y-2z = 0}$

how would I solve this problem? I know how to find the axis of rotation, but I can't seem to find a method to get the parametric equation on the new plane.

Comment: What’s wring with simply appling the rotation to the parameterization? Note, by the way, that there’s an infinite number of rotations that take the $x$-$z$ plane onto the one in your question, so there’s no such thing as “the” axis of rotation.

Answer (score 0):

The axis of rotation would be normal to the normals of both planes. The original curve lies in the $x-z$ plane, which would have a normal of $[0, 1,0]$.  The target plane has a normal of $[-3, 1, -2]$ so that means the axis of rotation would be $[0, 1, 0] \times [-3, 1, -2]$.